# Using HTML user input as a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, error-handling

I am trying to write a simple JavaScript function which should do the following:

- User enters a number in a HTML input field
- When the submit button is clicked, A JavaScript function alerts the user input on the screen.

For some reason the code does not run.

```js
function calcGuess() {
  var value = document.getElementById('userValue').value;
  alert(value);
}

document.getElementById("subButton").onclick = calcGuess();
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <form id='userInput'>
    <label id='numLabel' for='userValue'>Enter a Number:</label>
    <input id='userValue' type='number'></input>
    <button id='subButton' type='button'>Enter</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: For your onclick, pass the name of the function without the ().

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet" you see that the alert happens immediately upon page load. This is due to the use of parentheses after `calcGuess`.